# How Do I Remove Extra Spaces in Directories & Filenames / Filepaths in Windows

Tags: windows, filepath

I want to remove extra spaces in a number of filepaths as the filepaths under scrutiny are rather long.

For example, I have this filepath:

```
C:\TEST   Filepath\TEST   Filepath\TEST   Filepath\..\File.doc
```

and would like it to become:

```
C:\TEST Filepath\TEST Filepath\..\File.doc
```

I have hundreds of filepaths which are like this and would like to know if there is a quick and efficient way to remove the extra space from them?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are these filepaths physical paths or just strings collected in memory

Comment: in a specific programming language? or just plain cmd script?

Comment: These are all filepaths that physically exist (folders within folders) and I would like to know if there is a way to remove the extra spaces from them in order to save on the character count & length of said filepaths. Please note that the servers/systems where the data is stored all have limited access.

Comment: I am pretty sure that to change a physical path you need an administrative access (or something similar). But are you sure that this is a good idea? There is an high chance to broke existing applications that refers to these paths.

Comment: No, I have the ability to change filepaths - consider it 'somewhat restricted' access (not being able to access Task Manager, not able to change the date & time, etc).  There are no applications referring to these paths - all directories have been created and modified by either myself or a colleague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with a small set on a spare disk. Please be careful.

```
void RemoveExtraSpace(string sourceDir)
{
    var filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
    for(int x = filePaths.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        string cur = filePaths[x];
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(cur);
        if(rx.IsMatch(di.Name))
        {
            string result = Regex.Replace(di.Name, @"\s\s+", " ");
            result = Path.Combine(di.Parent.FullName, result);          
            Directory.Move(di.FullName, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to account for directories with spaces that contains directory with spaces (previous answer worked only on the last directory with spaces)